# " There exists either a computer scientist or a mathematician who knows both discrete math and C++ " what will be the logical equivalent sentence?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Assume,
$P(x) : x$ is a computer scientist. $M(x): x$ is a mathematician. $D(x) : x$ knows discrete math. $C(X) : x$ knows C++.

I translated the sentence into logical statement which is, $$∃x ( ( P(x) ∨ M(x) ) ∧ ( D(x) ∧ C(x) ) )$$
is it correct? and what will be the logically equivalent statement?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: Seems correct. What do you mean by "the logically equivalent statement"? How do you want to transform the statement? For example, you can use the following equivalence: $\exists x S(x)\equiv \neg\forall x \neg S(x)$, for some formula $S$. But there are other transformations, too.

Comment: The statement is ambiguous. For one, I'd always take *either-or* to be exclusive, but that may be up to taste. Secondly, should it be "There exists a person who is either a computer scientist or a matician, and this person knwos both discrete math and C++" or perhaps "Either a) there exists a computer scientist who knows both discrete math and C++ or b) there exists a mathematician who knwos both discrete math and C++". Not to mention what could be rewritten as "There exists either a mathematician who knows both discrete math and C++ or a computer scientist" ...